# Splitting data from a data.frame of length 1 by using a delimiter in R

Tags: r, split

I just imported a text file into R, and now I have a data frame of length 1. 
I had 152 reviews separated by a * character in that text file. Each review is like a paragraph long.

How can I get a data frame of length 152, each review being only 1 in the data frame ? I used this line to import the file into R :

```
myReviews <- read.table("C:/Users/Norbert/Desktop/research/Important files/Airline Reviews/Reviews/air_can_Review.txt", header=FALSE,sep="*")
```

(`myReview` has a length if 1 here.)... I need it to be 152, the number of reviews inside the text file.

How can I split the data from the data frame by the `"*"` delimiter, or just import the text file correctly by putting it into a data frame of length 152 instead of 1.

**EDIT : Example of the data**

I have 152 of this kind of data, all separated by `"*"`:

> I boarded Air Canada flight AC 7354 to Washington DCA the next morning, April 13th. After arriving at DCA, I
>   discovered to my dismay that the suitcase I had checked in at Tel Aviv was not on my flight. I spent 5 hours at
>   Pearson trying to sort out the mess resulting from the bumped connection.
>   *First time in 40 years to fly with Air Canada. We loved the slightly wider seats. Disappointed in no movies to
>   watch as not all travelers have i-phones etc. Also, on our trip down my husband asked twice for coffee, black. He
>   did not get any and was not offered anything else. On our trip home, I asked for a black coffee. She said she was
>   making more as several travelers had asked. I did not my coffee or anything else to drink. It was a long trip with
>   nothing to drink especially when they had asked. When trying to get their attention, they seemed to avoid my
>   tries. We found the two female stewardess's not very friendly. It may seem a small thing but very frustrating for
>   a traveler.
>   *Painless check-in. Two legs of 3 on AC: AC105, YYZ-YVR. Roomy and clean A321 with fantastic crew. AC33: YVR-SYD,
>   very light load and had 3 seats to myself. A very enthusiastic and friendly crew as usual on this transpacific
>   route that I take several times a year. Arrived 20 min ahead of schedule. The expected high level of service from
>   our flag carrier, Air Canada. Altitude Elite member.

They are airline reviews, each review separated by a *. I would like to take all of the reviews and put them in one data.frame in R, but each review should get its own "slot" or "position". The `"*"` is intended to be the separator.

Comment: @akrun ...it did not work. It gave me 712 lines and it deleted my previous work

Comment: Please provied an example of your original data.

Comment: @Molx, can you take a look at the data. I edited the question, as you asked. Can you suggest a way or a few lines how I can accomplish the data transfer into R, as explained in the editing.

Comment: I copy/pasted your data.  Tried `lines <- readLines('Review.txt'); lines1 <- strsplit(lines, '[*]')[[1]]`  It gave me 3 lines based on the `*`  Regarding each review should get its own slot, do you mean it as each column or as row?

Comment: Unless you plan on adding other types of data to each review and actually using a table, I don't see why you'd want them in a data.frame. Also, the `*` as a separator is not very reliable, you'll have problems if there are `*` characters in someone's review, for whatever reason.

Comment: yes, each review should get its own column